# CSS - How do I float one element to the right inside the other div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div, inside that div I have two smaller ones, one of them is to the left, and the other one is to the right, but the width of the parent div does not increase, how can I make it so it does?

I want the red div to get an increased height when the div's inside get bigger.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrap{
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;
    min-height:50px;
    background:red;
}

.left{
    width:450px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}

.right{
    width:450px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    float:right;
}

.footer{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:#000;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MZhZ/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add after your second div:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

or read about [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

Answer (score 3):

Add the following rule to the .wrap class `overflow: auto;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XXyXa/)**

```
.wrap{
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;
    min-height:50px;
    background:red;
    overflow: auto; /* <-- here */
}
```

Comment: @Michael check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/XXyXa/2/ Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9MZhZ/2/) with updated css. You just need to add overflow:hidden, and height:100%; in .wrap class.

```
.wrap {
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;
    min-height:50px;
    background:red;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use the CSS clearfix from [this site](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html). It's the most proper way to solve this problem. just set the class attribute of the .wrapper to "wrapper clearfix"

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
height: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the parent div to inherit. The height of the .wrap div will now expand based on the content inside:

```
.wrap
{
 margin:auto;
 width:960px;
 height:inherit;
 background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now when u increase the height of the left or right div, the main div height will also increase.

```
.wrap {
margin: auto;
width: 960px;
min-height: 50px;
background: red;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
}
```